# Possibility of Correlating Certain User Groups in low-latency Networks

Tags: anonymity, tor

Lets first assume some things:

1. There exists an Adversary
2. There exists a known Group of Users of a certain System.
3. The User can communicate to the System through a small set of (to user and adversary) well-known Servers.
4. The Adversary wants to know if a certain User communicated with the System
5. The Adversary has a lot of resources and can see all incoming communications to the Servers of the System. (Assume some kind of tap)
6. The User of the System wants to mitigate the risk of an adversary seeing their communication and use a low-latency anonymity Network like Tor.
7. The whole communication between User and Server uses approximately 3 packets and uses TLS/SSL.

The Question is now: How likely can the Adversary mount an attack, where he uses some kind of correlation or timing attack to determine if an user communicated with the System. Assume the Adversary furthermore can either tap all Users communications or has control of many of many of the Autonomous Systems where the users traffic comes from.

Comment: For #7 is the 3 packets after the TLS handshake?  I don't understand the overall question.

Comment: How does the Adversary's tap and TLS work together? Can A see the unencrypted traffic or only the encrypted traffic?

Answer (score 2):

First you look at the ingress part of the data. Fundamentally you put whatever sticks into the stream. Like modifying cookies or layer 6/7 session header injection. Later, you look at the egress packets. It doesn't matter that the connections are over an opaque cloud.

In fact, i think one can correlate the outgoing sets of packets from the origin host to the destination but that would probably require a lot of resources.